# Pulling data based on year, month, quarter

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have an input and output table as below. The input table is updated everyday. I need to find the value of the previous financial year, Previous month, previous quarter. I have written the query below for finding the previous financial year value.

case when ReportFinancialYear = 'FY19' then Value else null end as previous_financial_year_value

But i want to use ReportFinancialYear = current Financial Year-1, something like this. The similar formula for the remaining. Can anyone please assist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txwd1.png)

Comment: MySQL or BigQuery?

Comment: @ Tim, BigQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For BigQuery Standard SQL

A bit long, but I tested and does the job.

**Previous Financial Year:**

```
(CASE
    WHEN CAST(REPLACE(UPPER(ReportFinancialYear), "FY", "") AS INT64) + 2000 = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1 THEN Value
    ELSE NULL
END) AS previous_financial_year_value
```

**Previous Financial Quarter:**

```
(CASE
    WHEN ((CAST(REPLACE(UPPER(ReportFinancialYear), "FY", "") AS INT64) + 2000 = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1) AND (CAST(REPLACE(UPPER(ReportFinancialQuarter), "Q", "") AS INT64) = 4) AND (EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE) = 1)) OR (CAST(REPLACE(UPPER(ReportFinancialYear), "FY", "") AS INT64) + 2000 = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND (CAST(REPLACE(UPPER(ReportFinancialQuarter), "Q", "") AS INT64) = EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE) - 1)) THEN Value
    ELSE NULL
END) AS previous_financial_quarter_value
```

**Previous Month:**

```
(CASE
    WHEN ReportMonth = DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) THEN Value
    ELSE NULL
END) AS previous_financial_month_value
```

EDIT

Since you also asked for **current quarter**:

```
(CASE
    WHEN (CAST(REPLACE(UPPER(ReportFinancialYear), "FY", "") AS INT64) + 2000 = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)) AND (CAST(REPLACE(UPPER(ReportFinancialQuarter), "Q", "") AS INT64) = EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM CURRENT_DATE)) THEN Value
    ELSE NULL
END) AS current_financial_quarter_value
```

**Note:** I miscopied the query from previous_financial_quarter_value. Now it's updated and corrected.

Comment: @ Daniel, Thanks a lot. I also want to see current quarter value. Please give me a hints.

Comment: I added the query for current quarter. I also miscopied the query for previous quarter. Now it's correct.

Comment: @ Daniel, Thanks a lot. It is helpful.

Comment: @Nrad glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer though. It'll help me a lot.

Comment: @ Daniel, Hi Daniel,
With the same input table, I would like to get two more things.

1) FYQuarterToDate = "true" when ReportFinanacial Quarter is current Financial year and current Quarter, otherwise "false".
2) Previous week value.

Can you please assist on this.
Thanks a lot.